# MapReduce - Iterate on even values of an Iterable<Text>

Tags: java, mapreduce

I'm trying to solve a mapreduce problem. At the moment I got a method map that organizes my classes in this way :

```
    MapResult:    
    <key , "YES">
    <key , "NO">
    <key , "NO">
    <key , "YES">
```

What I have to do is to verify if there is at least one "YES" value in the even entries of this set , and at least one "YES" value in the odd entries of this set. In few words my condition is true if , for example , MapResult[0] == "YES" && MapResult[3] == YES.

Here is the code I need to complete for the reduce task :

```
public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

      for (Text value : values) {
        // Iteration on this values
      }

      //context.write();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over the iterable and "flip" the check for even and odd elements:

boolean result = false;
boolean evenFound = false;
boolean oddFound = false;
boolean checkEven = true;

```
for (Text value : values) {
   if (checkEven) {
       evenFound |= "YES".equals(value);
   } else {
       oddFound |= "YES".equals(value);
   }

   if (evenFound && oddFound) {
       result = true;
       break;
   }

   checkEven = !checkEven;
}
```